# How do I fix this error on this command thanks.... Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java

```
public class GörüntüAlma {

    public static void main  (String [] args  ){




    26---> (error)PlanarImage resim=JAI.create(null, args[0]);

    String Sresim = "boyut= " + resim.getWidth() + "X" +resim.getHeight()+ "Grup=" + resim.getNumBands()  ;

    JFrame tablo = new JFrame();
    tablo.setTitle("Göster:" + args [0]);

    Container Pane =tablo.getContentPane();
    Pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    DisplayJAI dj= new DisplayJAI(resim);

    Pane.add(new JScrollPane(dj),BorderLayout.CENTER);

    Pane.add(new JLabel(Sresim),BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        tablo.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        tablo.setSize(400,400);
        tablo.setVisible(true);





    }


}
```

How do I fix this error on this command thanks
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at görüntü.işleme.sb.GörüntüAlma.main(GörüntüAlma.java:26)

Comment: Do you know what the `args` parameter is used for? Are you using it correctly?

Answer (score 2):

```
JAI.create(null, args[0]);
```

You forget to check what happens if `args` is empty; in this case, there is nothing at index 0. Hence the error: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`.

Solution: check that your array is empty and exit early in this case. Before this line:

```
if (args.length == 0) {
    System.err.println("I expect at least one argument");
    System.exit(2);
}
```

Addendum: no idea how you launch your program in the first place, but it looks like you pass no arguments to it at all... The code above will tell you about that.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question at all. What are you passing as an argument?

Comment: args array is empty I want to upload images to this series 
note: I do not know english (google translate